# Is there a more productive way to build and test components?

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I would like to know how everyone else is writing their components and testing them out?

The way I am doing it seems to be taking too long, so I hope someone could maybe point something obvious that I might have overlooked or could do instead to make the whole process of building my own components more enjoyable and not such a dogged lengthy task.

This is along the lines of what I am doing with one of my current components (with the package open as the project, and the component already installed in the IDE):

1. Make changes to the component code.
2. Build with Shift+F9.
3. If adding a new published property to my component I uninstall / reinstall the component again.
4. Add a new Form.
5. Drop my recently built component on the form.
6. Check at design time to see if the properties can be correctly changed and the control is painted correctly (also see if new published properties show in Object Inspector). Also check for any errors in the component.
7. If at design time everything seems ok, I save the package and close it then create a new Application.
8. Then I add again my component to the new Form of the new Application project and run it to see how it works at run time.
9. Some further modifications to the component can be changed without opening the package again, ie if it is a paint procedure of my component I can just open the source unit of the component, change it and re run the Application to see the changes.
10. Any other modifications and I usually need to close the whole project again, and reopen the package and repeat all the steps above.

I am constantly switching between the component package and new application project to make changes, there has to be a much more efficient way of doing this and I bet there is but I cannot see it!

I will accept the answer to the person who can save me a lot of time and cut out most of the steps above if it is possible:)

Comment: Rather than rebuilding the package each time, you can just do a Clean and Build on the test project.

That, however, won't work when changing Published Properties!

Comment: I could publish an IDE plugin which streamlines the package rebuild process (roll together Uninstall, Clean, Build, Install all into a single context menu entry and hotkey). Would that be useful to anyone other than me?

Comment: Try to test your comp in runtime - it will be much faster then design time. If you don't know how to test components in runtime - ask me.

Comment: With the few components I've done, I've found that simply building the project with the component unit present incorporates any of my new changes.  The only time you have to reinstall the component is if you change any design-time attributes.

Comment: I too advocate for testing your component at runtime rather than install/reinstall overhead, unless you're testing some special property editor, you can get away with creating the component at runtime within an event.

Comment: Yep, forget about the package and just build the component from source into a test app.

Comment: @LaKraven that sounds like a really useful plugin, I am sure others would find it beneficial too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need to perform the steps from 4. more than once?

I generally create a program group and add the following to it:

- A runtime package that contains all the runtime units.
- A designtime package that installs the component and implements any design time editors.
- A demo project that allows properties of the component to be changed via a GUI.

When I make changes to the component I simply rebuild the demo project and run it. If I make changes to the properties of the component I rebuild the runtime package then install the design time package. After doing this, display the demo form again and the Delphi IDE will warn you of any missing components. No need to recreate anything.

If you want to see an example, take a look at my [TChromeTabs](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-chrome-tabs/) source.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. I never thoght that component developement will require that much operatins.

My common workflow looks like that:

1. Open Project group with my component packages (run-time and design-time) and test programs
2. Modify component code
3. Rebuild component package
4. Switch to test program's form with that component to see if it looks ok in Design-time
5. Run test program from IDE to see if it works in Run-time
6. And, occasionally I run a batch file that compiles my component and all the test programs in a clean environment (without using all the precompiled .dcu files) for each Delphi version that I have. Just to test that component can be compiled correctly in both Delphi 6 and Delphi 2010 (which are used in our company).

I use [Lazy Delphi Builder](http://www.LazyProject.info/) to make a "clean compile" (compile without using full Delphi Library path). A separate LazyDBP profile for each IDE. And a .bat file that runs them all.